UK Online Safety Act 2023 - provider or access facility?
The Online Safety Act introduces a new set of requirements for providers of a "user-to-user service" such as online forums.
It isn't clear which entity counts as the provider of such a service.
Two relevant definitions are:

In this Act “user-to-user service” means an internet service by means
of which content that is generated directly on the service by a user
of the service, or uploaded to or shared on the service by a user of
the service, may be encountered by another user, or other users, of
the service.


For the purposes of this section, a facility is an “access facility”
in relation to a regulated service if the person who provides the
facility is able to withdraw, adapt or manipulate it in such a way as
to impede access (by means of that facility) to the regulated service
(or to part of it) by United Kingdom users of that service.
Examples of access facilities include—
(a) internet access services by means of which a regulated service is
made available, and
(b) app stores through which a mobile app for a regulated service may
be downloaded or otherwise accessed.

The question I would like answered is which entity counts as the provider of a forum using https://plushforums.com; PlushForums or the person who subscribes to their software and hosting.
Given that it's cloud software-as-a-service, with subscribers having no control over the software itself (other than in-built administration functionality), I would have thought that PlushForums count as the provider of any forums, but they are claiming that they only count as an "access facility" and so that the legal requirements fall on the person paying for a subscription.

We can't give legal advice, so I won't comment on whether PlushForums specifically are a provider or not. However, the relevant definition is the one at Section 226(2) - (3) of the Act:

(2) The provider of a user-to-user service is to be treated as being
the entity that has control over who can use the user-to-user part of
the service (and that entity alone).
(3) If no entity has control over who can use the user-to-user part of
a user-to-user service, but an individual or individuals have control
over who can use that part, the provider of the service is to be
treated as being that individual or those individuals.

Also, being a provider of an access facility does not make you a provider of a user-to-user service, pursuant to Section 226(12):

A person who provides an access facility in relation to a user-to-user
service, within the meaning of section 146, is not to be regarded as a
person who has control over who can use the user-to-user part of the
service for the purposes of this section.

So, to identify who the provider is of an online forum you need to look at who is controlling user access.

I think the way to view this is that PlushForums is acting as an agent for the customers who set up their forums. So the customers are the providers, and they've outsourced operation of this to PlushForums, which hosts it on their cloud servers, which is the access facility.
